# Error Domain=io.grpc Code=14 "OS Error"

Tags: google-speech-api

I'm using google iOS client library
to access the gRPC streaming speech to text service.
Sometimes I get the error below:

Error Domain=io.grpc Code=14 "OS Error"

Does anyone know I get this error and how I can fix it?
Thanks!